# Using FILTER in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: filter, spreadsheet

Can someone please explain to me what I am missing in this statement. I am wanting sum if both filter statements are true....

=SUM(FILTER(D3:D28<=&G5,D3:D28>=&G4)B3:B31)

Comment: What error are you getting, or what is the result and why is it wrong? Can you show us the spreadsheet itself so we know what kind of data we are dealing with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the sumifs function (from Google Spreadsheets' explanation: SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criterion1, [criteria_range2, criterion2, ...])

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is sumproduct

Sumproduct((range1)*(range2<=value)*(range3>=value))